# Which Java library for creating Solaris pkg software packages?

Tags: java, solaris

Which Java library are people using to create Solaris pkg software packages? We are developing an application that has, as one if its features, the ability to bundle backend services as a pkg software package which can be easily installed in Solaris. I am hoping that there is a Java library that makes building pkg's a painless process.

If there is no library for this could you point me to a resource that describes how to build a pkg?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any particular experience with it but you could maybe use the [solaris-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/solaris/solaris-maven-plugin/) which seems to be a wrapper around `pkgmk` and `pkgtrans`. See the [usage](http://mojo.codehaus.org/solaris/solaris-maven-plugin/usage.html) guide and the [Best Practices and Examples](http://mojo.codehaus.org/solaris/solaris-maven-plugin/best-practice-and-examples.html)  document to get an idea of the involved steps.

See also [ant script and solaris package](http://www.coderanch.com/t/107788/tools/ant-script-solaris-package) for an ant based example (which also just calls the `pkgmk` and `pkgtrans` commands).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am more looking for a Java library that I can use to programmatically create a pkg software package that can then be taken to a Solaris system and installed. I can't rely on pkgmk being installed on the system.

Comment: 100% Java isn't going to happen. You could grab the source of the maven plugin and adapt to your non-maven needs.

Answer (score 0):

[heirloom](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/pkgtools.html) might be an option if you are on linux ... but still not java :( binaries for redhat are [here](http://koji.spacewalkproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=6952), there should be something for ubuntu as well. debian i could not find.